# How to add a list of figures row by row?

Tags: floats

I tried to add a list of figures row by row but they interfere with other sections not sure how to fix.

[image]

The figures are all of the same size 6in.
Conclusion Section is interfering with the last (5th) picture, I tried bigskip, newpage, pagebreak not working.

```
\subsubsection{Results}
\begin{paragraph}
\space The table \ref{table:res} summarizes the results we got from the experiment.


Graphical Results (Solution Time, Speed up, Efficiency):
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6in]{images/100t.png}
    \caption{Solution Time Vs Number of Processors M = 100}
    \label{fig:100t}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6in]{images/200t.png}
    \caption{Solution Time Vs Number of Processors M = 200}
    \label{fig:200t}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width =6in]{images/500t.png}
    \caption{Solution Time Vs Number of Processors M = 500}
    \label{fig:500t}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width =6in]{images/1000t.png}
    \caption{Solution Time Vs Number of Processors M = 1000}
    \label{fig:1000t}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6in]{images/2000t.png}
    \caption{Solution Time Vs Number of Processors M = 2000}
    \label{fig:2000t}
\end{figure}

\end{paragraph}
\pagebreak
\section{Conclusion}
```

Thanks.

Comment: use `\clearpage` not `\pagebreak` after the figures (and use `[ht]` not `[h]`.. Also `\paragraph` is a section heading, after `\subsubsection`  not an environment, but you show `\end{paragraph}` in your fragment, that looks wrong???

Comment: thank you! It worked. I'll fix it, also Mr.David my figures show non-English captions any ideas why?

Comment: some code you have not shown (babel or polyglossia packages most likely) will have set the default language, but as you have shown no code, impossible to guess.

Comment: Thank you very much I solved foreign language issue 2. I hope you have a great day, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\clearpage` not `\pagebreak` after the figures (and use `[ht]` not `[h]`)